# How to highllight the listview items?

Tags: android

I am using LinearLayout (orientation = horizontal) for the listview items. And this linearlayout contains imageview and textview. I want to highlight the complete linearlayout manager of the listview item which one is touch by the user.

What is the good way to achieve it in the xml?

Comment: by default a list view item will be highlighted when touched by the user ashish

Comment: Are want to behave like a button click or do You want to leave it highlightet?

Answer (score 1):

you can create any custom selector that you want for your listview .please see [ListView item background via custom selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector)
and
[Selector for custom list view "Change ListView background - strange behaviour"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989908/selector-for-custom-list-view-change-listview-background-strange-behaviour)

Comment: This is the solution that I'm also using.